# Defer inline scripts in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I am working on a Wordpress website with Gutenberg builder, I finally manage to add the async and defer to the scripts, but inline script are which is depend on the defer scripts giving error. I am not able to add defer to those inline scripts
Those scripts have **id** tag in theme

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='wp-blocks-js-translations'>
...
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' id='wp-data-js-after'>
....
<script>
```

Is there any way to add defer to these inline scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Inline and internal Javascript will load with the HTML page, so they do not require an additional request in order to load. Therefore you don't need to use async/defer on the script tag.